# Imported Android project still refers to external libraries but can't find them

Tags: android, eclipse, import, adt, libraries

I imported an Android project into Eclipse (Custom ADT). During the import process, I chose to copy project into Workspace.

My project could compile and run well but after sometime, it stopped working. When I check in the 'Problems' View, I see that it still looks for the BIN folder in the folder from which the project was imported and it can't find the library it wants to reference.

Aren't Libraries copied along with the project in Android? How do I fix this?

Comment: is there a libs folder inside your project ?

Comment: can u clean the project

Comment: @Sree, I there is a 'libs' folder in my project.

Comment: @Giridharan, I have tried that several times but instead, the problem gets worse each time. The R class even gets deleted and I have to restore the project from local history to get the R class back.

Comment: OK check inside that is the library there, else add inside that,if want more help plz ask

Comment: @Sree, I have the libraries in place. They are in fact just the support libraries (v4 & v13) that I am not even using in the app yet. Is there a way I can change their location and referencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to add external JARs to your Android project or any Java project is:

1. **Create a folder called `libs`** in your project's root folder - you already had this
2. Copy your **JAR files to the `libs` folder**
3. Now **right click on the Jar file and then select Build Path > Add to Build
   Path**, which will create a folder called 'Referenced Libraries' within your
   project

   By doing this, **you will not
   lose your libraries** that are being referenced on your
   hard drive whenever you transfer your project to another computer.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick but introduced another problem. My R.java is missing. +1 for this tip.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the Libraries into your libs folder before you copy/import. Because if you just added the Library over the Build-path its just copy the Reference, not the Library itself.

Comment: The libraries I have and that are being referenced are just support libraries (v4 & v13) that I think just get added to every new project by the Android SDK itself. I did not add any new library myself to the project.